# Shortcut to open specific link in specific chrome profile

Tags: windows, google-chrome, shortcuts

Is there a way to create a shortcut to a site in a specific Chrome account?

For example, I might want to open bbc.co.uk in my Home profile via a desktop shortcut
Or, I might want to open my-work-homepage.org in my Work profile via a shortcut.

Currently, shortcuts open in whatever Profile was last used

PLEASE NOTE - I don't want to just open the profile at its startup page - I want to open a specific link in a specific profile.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: So what have you tried? Is setting a specific page as the start page acceptable workaround?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Setting a specific page as the start page is not good enough - I need a desktop shortcut that will open a specific url in a specific chrome profile.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=shortcut+chrome+profile

Comment: Yes - lots of questions about chrome profiles, nothing specifically about the question I have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a shortcut that looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="PROFILE-NAME" URL
```

In case of a problem, a surer method to create the shortcut
(without the URL part) is via Chrome:

- Click the person icon on top-right
- Click the icon to the right of the text "Other profiles"
- Click the three-points icon for the wanted profile and select "Edit"
- Select theme and icon for the desktop shortcut
- Enable "Create desktop shortcut" to create the shortcut on your desktop
- Right-click the shortcut and select Properties, to add the URL.

To delete the shortcut from the desktop, disable "Create desktop shortcut".

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks